# Parse UDP received data on Python

Tags: python, parsing, udp

I'm programming an analogic remote control receiving data through UDP. The receiver is running python3 to analyze this received data. I would like to extract specific data and store it on variables. The received data format is like so:

```
{RX: SIGNED INTEGER VALUE, RY: SIGNED INTEGER, LX: SIGNED INTEGER,
 LY: SIGNED INTEGER}
```

The matter is that the values coming from the buffer data are not patronized and varies between -255,0 and 255. Is there any way to store those incoming variables into Python variables even the integers are not patronized like -000, 255 or -255?

The data is comming in 100ms interval from the Virtual Joystick.

```
import socket
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
print "received message:", data

# Example received data: {RX:, -123, RY:, 321, LX:, 0, LY:, 10}

RX = "extracted integer from packet" # From example int -123
RY = "extracted integer from packet" # From example int 321
LX = "extracted integer from packet" # From example int 0
LY = "extracted integer from packet" # From example int 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just after a JSON parser, e.g:

```
import socket
import json

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print('received data', data)

    msg = json.loads(data.decode('ascii'))
    print('parsed message', msg)

    print('LX =', msg['LX'])
```

note that I'm using Python 3 syntax, as Python 2 is due to become unsupported in a [couple of months](https://pythonclock.org/)